# If the $(a) = (b)$, then $a = ub$ for some unit: Convert geometric proof to ring theoretic proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

$\DeclareMathOperator{Spec}{Spec}\DeclareMathOperator{support}{support}$
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $a, b \in R$. If $(a) = (b)$, then we wish to show that there is some unit $u \in R^\times$ such that $a = ub$.

---

Let us use the geometric viewpoint for intuition. Let $R$ be the ring of smooth functions on a compact smooth manifold $M$. Thus, $a, b \in R$ are smooth functions on $M$.

$(a) = (b)$ implies the support of $a$ equals the support of $b$.

For a proof, since $a \in (a) = (b)$, we have $a \in (b)$, ie, there is a function $f \in R$ such that $a = fb$. Thus, $a(p) \neq 0 \implies f(p)b(p) \neq 0 \implies b(p) \neq 0$. Thus, $\support(a) \subseteq \support(b)$. By symmetry, we get $\support(b) \subseteq \support(a)$. In total, we have $\support(a) = \support(b)$. This allows us to create a function $u$:

$$
u(p) \equiv
\begin{cases}
b(p)/a(p) & a(p) \neq 0 \\
0 & a(p) = 0
\end{cases}
$$

We see that $b = ua$. If $u$ is supported everywhere on $M$ (ie, $support(u) = M$), then $u$ is a unit in $R$ such that $(a) = (b)$. $\blacksquare$

---

I wish to translate the above geometric intuition into algebraic geometry. I believe I should be able to treat $a$ and $b$ as functions on $\Spec(R)$, and repeat the argument as above. Here's my attempt:

Since $(a) = (b)$, this implies that $a = fb$ for some element $f \in R$. Consider a point (prime ideal) $\mathfrak p \subseteq R$. Since $a \equiv_{\mathfrak p} fb$, if $a \not \equiv_{\mathfrak p} 0$, this means $fb \not \equiv_{\mathfrak p} 0$, or that $f \not \equiv _{\mathfrak p} 0$ and $b \not \equiv_{\mathfrak p} 0$. But how do we proceed further?

1. To create $u_{\mathfrak p} \equiv_{\mathfrak p} b/a$, we need some way to invert the $a \in R/\mathfrak p$. How do we do this?
2. Even if we succeed in creating all the $u(\mathfrak p)$, how do we glue the solutions together to get an element $u \in R$?

I feel knowing how to translate the geometric argument above into algebraic geometry will really help me see the power of (affine) schemees.

Comment: But the claim that $(a)=(b)$ implies $a=ub$ for a unit $u$ is not true  in general, for a commutative ring - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984399/if-a-b-does-there-exists-a-unit-u-such-that-a-ub-for-commutative).

Comment: Your calculation and method will work if you take $R$ to be an integral domain.

Comment: @JakeLevinson Could you elaborate in an answer how this can be made to work on an integral domain? I'd really like to see the details to understand _concretely_ how to translate the geometric proof to AG!